# google scripts/html trying to display page within page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

First I am going to show my code, this is my html code that's running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Elliots Site</title>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Gcss'); ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page">
      <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;" src="http://google.com" width="100" height="100" scrolling="no">Iframes not supported</iframe>
      <h1 class="emoj">""</h1>
     </div> 
        <?!= include('Gjavascript'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my css file:

```
<style>
    /* CSS reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
      html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.page iframe {
vertical-align:center;
width=200%;
height=100%;
}
.page .emoj {
text-align:center;
color:auto;
vertical-align:center;
}
.page{
background-color:white;
align-items: center;
height:400px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align:center;
}
<style>
```

I also have two more files to run the code and apply the css file, which I am pretty sure is not the issue. This first one is a gs file which is a form of js the code starts at doGet

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('gindex')
.evaluate();
}
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

and the other one which is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

Okay now the question. The current result is just a blank page, and its not even printing the text. so far i haven't tried anything that led to much success, so far i have worked on the css file to try to fix it. I have done research, but couldn't find much on google scripts. the goal of the code is to display google homepage inside of the site, I have been deploying it as a web page. This my first post If you have questions I could answer or test for please let me know

Comment: Using only these tags is adequate for css `<style></style>`  And if you not doing templated html you can put them all on the same page.

Comment: ok thanks for responding i will do this but will this fix the issue or just a general suggestion

Comment: someone help me plz

Comment: :'(:'(:'(:-(:-(:-(

Comment: I have updated the code to ironixx's URL and two lines of code, <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: while this was probably part of the issue it is not showing up still, probably one more bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a bit messy by how it's provided so for demo purposes I made my own. If you want to "embed" google.com first page to your site then use iframe but instead of using google.com try to use this link => https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1 otherwise it will show nothing.

P.S. To preview code use full-page mode.

```css
        
        .frame {
            height: 700px;
            width: 600px;
        }
        
        .page {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        body {
            background-color: grey;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IRONIXX</title>

</head>
<body>
    <section class="page">
        <h1 class="emoj">""</h1>
        <iframe class="frame" src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: holy cow! this is amazing I will test the new URL in my code(wouldn't want steal your work) but also you don't know how helpful it is to study the same code with the same concepts i was using, but formatted better. I am so thankful you gave the time not only to try and help with the issue but rewrite the code as well

Comment: @ElliotMassey - feel free to use it how you want/need if it helps to solve your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't solve your blank page scenario directly, but if you're interested in nesting another site within yours perhaps you'd be interested in using an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead?

[Here's a generator](https://www.iframe-generator.com/). Try punching in `google.com` and see if you can embed it in your site.

Comment: I have transitioned to iframe (i must say i forgot about them i used iframes in the beginning but started using other stuff to try to fix the error) i will update the post and would love more solutions or general feedback!